# How to prevent lemmatization of proper nouns in phrases

Tags: python, nltk

I have a column where i store russian phrases which i use to target people through pay per click ads systems. I want to lemmatize these phrases but between them have phrases which contains shops' names. I want to lemmatize all phrases but prevent lemmatization of these shops' names in phrase. Here is sample for my input data

```
купить машину на Авито
купить кондиционеры Люком
цены на кухни Киргу
```

Capitalized words in input data sample is shops' names. I tried to create function for doing it in Python using Pymorphy2. Here is my code for lemmatization
Sorry for my bad English

```
stops = stopwords.words('russian')
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
def lemmatization_func(x):
words_from_phrase = x.split()
#print(words_from_phrase)
phrase=[]
unique=[]
for word in words_from_phrase:
    if word not in stops:
        lemma = morph.parse(word)
        #print(lemma)
        for item in lemma:
            phrase.append(item.normal_form)


#print(len(phrase))

for i in phrase:
    if i not in unique:
        unique.append(i)


#print(unique)


p_a = ' '.join(str(e) for e in unique)
return p_a 

x = "купить машину на Авито"
j = lemmatization_func(x)
print(j)
```

Comment: Hmm, in classical tokenization algorithms you would have predefined strings and/or regex matchings that would capture such special phrases. However, this seems like the problem is specific to the Russian language and pymorphy2 so maybe you will have more luck at the russian stackoverflow https://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: It might be helpful if you post sample input data and the expected output.

Comment: I added sample of input data in my post